# "Token second\team not found and default index is not set" error in torchtext function

Tags: python, nlp, torchtext

This is my code, the function work well for train set but for test set returns this error `RuntimeError: Token second\team not found and default index is not set`

```
train_data, train_labels = text_classification._create_data_from_iterator(
    vocab, text_classification._csv_iterator(train_csv_path, ngrams, yield_cls=True), False)
test_data, test_labels = text_classification._create_data_from_iterator(
    vocab, text_classification._csv_iterator(test_csv_path, ngrams, yield_cls=True), False)
```

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vocabulary acts as a lookup table for your data translating `str` to `int`. When a given string (in this case "second\team") doesn't appear in the vocabulary, there are two strategies to compensate:

1. Throw an error because you don't know how to handle it. Imagine something like a `KeyError` when calling `{}[1]` in Python
2. Assign a default "unknown" token to the missing tokens. Imagine a default value like `{}.get(1, "I don't know!")` in Python.

Your code is currently doing #1. You seem to want #2 which you can achieve using `vocab.set_default_index`. When you build your vocab, add the `specials=["<unk>"]` kwarg and then call `vocab.set_default_index(vocab['<unk>'])`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! it solved my problem. :)